# How do I get Swashbuckle to have Swagger UI to group by Version?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am playing with the new Azure API Apps (template in Visual Studio 2013 w/ the new SDK bits from 3/24/15) and I'd like have my Swagger UI group my calls by Version #. In my case, I'm currently versioning by URI (I realize REST purists will tell me not to do this - please don't try to "correct my error" here). For instance, I may have these calls:

```
http://example.com/api/Contacts <-- "latest"
http://example.com/api/1/Contacts
http://example.com/api/2/Contacts
http://example.com/api/Contacts{id} <-- "latest"
http://example.com/api/1/Contacts/{id}
http://example.com/api/2/Contacts/{id}
```

Functionally, this works great! (Yes, I know some of you will cringe. Sorry this hurts your feelings.) However, my problem is w/ Swagger UI organization. By default, Swagger UI groups these by the Controller Name (`Contacts` in this case). I see in the `SwaggerConfig.cs` file that I can change this:

```
// Each operation be assigned one or more tags which are then used by consumers for various reasons.
// For example, the swagger-ui groups operations according to the first tag of each operation.
// By default, this will be controller name but you can use the "GroupActionsBy" option to
// override with any value.
//
//c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc => apiDesc.HttpMethod.ToString());
```

What I don't understand is how I can tweak this to group all of the "latest" together and then all of v1 together and then all of v2 together, etc.

How can I do this? If it absolutely must require that I add the word "latest" (or equiv) into the path in place of the version number, then I can do that but I'd prefer not have to do that.

Comment: P.S. I know Swashbuckle/Swagger support other versioning settings. If I should work with others to help make this easier/possible/better, do please point this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you're looking to do is to uncomment a line a few lines below that one in SwaggerConfig.cs

```
c.OrderActionGroupsBy(new DescendingAlphabeticComparer());
```

except you'd change the name of the class to something like ApiVersionComparer() and then implement it as a new class:

```
public class ApiVersionComparer : IComparer<string>
{

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        // Write whatever comparer you'd like to here.
        // Yours would likely involve parsing the strings and having
        // more complex logic than this....
        return -(string.Compare(x, y));
    }
}
```

If you've gotten far enough to ask this question, I'm sure I can leave the sort implementation for you. :-)